# displaying date & time

Tags: java, android, date, time

I want to display date and time separately, but application crashes instead. If i remove time side of it, then it doesn't crash. But I really need to display date on one place and time separitely on the other place.

```
    // date & time \\
    // date
    dateatm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MMM/dd");
    String dateNow = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime());
    dateatm.setText(dateNow);
    // time
    timeatm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
    Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat värk = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    String timeNow = värk.format(currentTime.getTime());
    timeatm.setText(timeNow);
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:text="Tere " android:id="@+id/tvTere"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/date"
    android:text="kuupäev" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="20dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:gravity="center"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/time"
    android:text="kellaaeg" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="20dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:gravity="center"></TextView>
```

Error in

```
08-10 16:22:13.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-10 16:22:13.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{viimane.voimalus/viimane.voimalus.MainStuff}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-10 16:22:13.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
08-10 16:22:13.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-10 16:22:13.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-10 16:22:13.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-10 16:22:13.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-10 16:22:13.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-10 16:22:13.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-10 16:22:13.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-10 16:22:13.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-10 16:22:13.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-10 16:22:13.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-10 16:22:13.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-10 16:22:13.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-10 16:22:13.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at viimane.voimalus.MainStuff.onCreate(MainStuff.java:52)
08-10 16:22:13.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-10 16:22:13.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-10 16:22:13.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Crash how? What exception do you get?

Comment: Could you post layout xml that contains `R.id.time` and error text from logcat?

Comment: It would help if you provided a stack trace from logcat. I'm guessing that you are getting either a NullPointerException when you call `timeatm.setText(timeNow)` or a ClassCastException when you try to initialize `timeatm`. If this is the case, the problem is that the content view does not contain a TextView with id `time`.

Comment: @Kai - I updated with all info you asked :). I hope it helps!

Comment: What is in the line 52 in your MainStuff class?

Comment: Logcat is log. (Sorry, couldn't resist...)

Comment: @user802421 timeatm.setText(timeNow); - yes alex, I didnt know what catlog is till now :P. I am still new to android :)

Comment: @Elven hehe I was just making a bad joke ("Longcat is long" is a famous silly meme), not telling you off! :)

Comment: Don't worry about it Alex :P. I still need help with that stuff tho :P

Comment: I recommend only getting one calendar instance, and then supplying it to two different formatters.  Should help with possible timing update anomalies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field "timeatm" is null at at line 52. Meaning findViewById() did not find the component "time" in the layout. Sure you have the right XML layout file set with setContentView(), and setContentView() is called before the code above?

Note (in general) that findViewById() does NOT fail if it does not find a component - it just returns null. In the interest of catching errors ("fail early"), ALWAYS check the result of findViewById for null and throw an exception. Your code will fail in either case, but using this method you will know what is going on (i.e. you messed up your layout, chose the wrong layout, take your pick -.- in essence, you are guarding against future errors by yourself or other maintainers of your code).

Comment: I made extra check. It was ok. So i made small change. I changed time to vtTime and then time in java to vtTime as well and then it was fixed suddenly, thank you very much!

Comment: Sometimes the Eclipse ADT is slow to pick up changes in the XML. If you have the feeling that something fishy is going on, performing  Project > Clean... might help (has helped me a lot in the past).

Answer (score 0):

Things look right on the first glance.

As the other users proposed, this should be connected to the xml file.

You maybe have some error there - either you misspelled some id (not highly possible, especially if you don't have other xml layout files), or the views aren't TextViews.

BTW, where do you place this source - after calling setContentView() ? This maybe the error - if you call it before, it won't work, the view won't be inflated.